# Question about JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var month = new array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

    var mon;
    mon = month(m);

    var today = m+"/"+d+"/"+y
    $('#calendar').append('<div id="today">Today is'+' '+mon+'/'+d+'/'+y+'.');

});
```

Comment: Are you doing *what* right? ... What's your question?

Comment: No, you’re doing it wrong, starting with the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `mon = month(m);` use square bracket notation: `mon = month[m];` and `new array()` should be `new Array()` or better yet, use an array literal, like `['First','Second','Third']`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

    var mon;
    mon = month[m];

    var today = m+"/"+d+"/"+y
    $('#calendar').append('<div id="today">Today is'+' '+mon+'/'+d+'/'+y+'.');

});
```

Comment: Careful, Andrew. With mind-reading skills like that, someone will kidnap you and sell you to a carnival. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't close your `<div id="today">` tag. Add `</div>` into your code.

Like so:

```
$('#calendar').append('<div id="today">Today is'+' '+mon+'/'+d+'/'+y+'.'+'</div>');
```